# What is this error after a database Restore operation at my hosting provider?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting, database-restore

I'm currently trying a migration of my database from discountasp.net to arvixe.com, mainly to check if I can get the same level of quality for a better price. I made a backup of my database at discountasp through their control panel, uploaded it via ftp to the new host and used their restore tool. I then open SQL Server Management Studio, open my database node and the Tables node. I then get the following error and I can't see anything in the Tables node same happens for other nodes too, like Security/Users)

> Failed to retrieve data for this request (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database
>   'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

I was always able to backup/restore DBs from/to discountasp and my local dev machine.

**Is it an error very specific to the tested host Arvixe or is it an error that someone is able to explain?** No need to say that before the restore, at Arvixe, I was able to create a database, tables, look inside and play with it. This is really the restore operation that screws up everything.

PS: of course I have an open ticket with Arvixe too but so far they are not able to help...

**Update**: this issue had no explanation. Under Arvixe CP, I created another user, gave it access to the database and it worked. I (and Arvixe) have no idea why the first user had a change in its permissions to prevent me accessing the restored DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no user mapped to the restored database with the right you need to do a simple select. (custom) users are not transferred with a backup/restore.

I' don't know ik you can get to the security node, but there you should add the mapping to your user account.

This t-sql script adds YourUserName user as db_owner to YourDatabaseName

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'YourUserName'
GO
```

Suceess!

Comment: No this does not work. What you describe is what happens just after the restore. My username has not been reassociated with the DB. So to do that I select my username through their control panel and hit Update. After that I can open my database node. But I still get the same error on nested nodes like Tables (even if I use your script).

Comment: It sure looks like a permission problem. Maybe at arvixe.com they have different permissions/schema's set up... Did the script runs without errors? You said that you could restore it locally? What if you add the user account of arvixe.com to your local database and open SSMS with that account?

Comment: Found this on http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic400182-146-1.aspx#bm400192

use master
go
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO user_login;
go

Comment: running this gives: Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: Did you get any help from arvixe?